# Упорядочить строки по возрастанию количества различных элементов

Tags: c#, winforms

Помогите пожалуйста с решением задачки.
Моя задумка была в том, чтобы из двумерной матрицы (не обращайте внимание, что там двумерный лист) вытаскивать строки, узнавать сколько в них различных элементов и записывать их в другой массив (соответственно по строкам). Далее находить в массиве  (в котором записаны значения по строкам) минимальный элемент и соответствующую строку ставить на первое место в матрице, но смогла сделать только для одной строки  . То есть, если массив, который хранит значение различных элементов (по строкам соответственно) будет {6, 6, 4, 6, 6, 5}, то нужно поставить строки матрицы по возрастанию различных элементов {4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6}

```
//Arr1 - двумерный лист тип double
double[] tempArray = new double[n];   
int[] counterDifferentNumber = new int[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        tempArray[j] = Arr1[i][j];
    }
    counterDifferentNumber[i] = tempArray.Distinct().Count();
}
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    MessageBox.Show(counterDifferentNumber[i].ToString());
}
int min = 6;
double tempNum;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    min = SearchMin(counterDifferentNumber); // просто вызывается функция нахождения минимального числа
    if (counterDifferentNumber[i] == min && counterDifferentNumber[i] != n)
    {
        for (int q = 0; q < n; q++)
        {
            tempNum = Arr1[0][q];
            Arr1[0][q] = Arr1[i][q]; 
            Arr1[i][q] = tempNum;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вам нужна функция, которая считает характеристику строки. Далее берете любой метод сортировки (пузырек), сравниваете строки по характеристике и меняете.

Comment: Можно и со вспомогательным массивом. Тогда берете метод сортировки, сравниваете для строк i, j элементы вспомогательного массива, меняете и строки и элементы вспомогательного массива.